# Chain rule applied in one point

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative, chain-rule

Let $g(u, v)=e^u + \sin v$ and $f(x, y, z)=(xy, xz)$ . Calculate $D(g o f)$ in $(0,1,0)$ applying chain rule.
So here is what I have done:
$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial g1}{\partial u} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial g2}{\partial u} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = e^u * y + 1*y + \cos v * z $$
$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial g1}{\partial u} \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial g2}{\partial u} \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = e^u * x + u*y $$
$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial z} = \frac{\partial g2}{\partial v} \frac{\partial v}{\partial z}  = \cos v * x $$
I think I am going in a good way but I do not know what I should do now.

Comment: g1, g2? What do you mean? I think you forgot to include g2 in your definition of g

Comment: I have a question. What is senv?

Comment: So g(g1, g2). And senv = sen(v).

Comment: I'm pretty sure you mean $\sin(v)$ instead of $\text{sen}(v)$ but I might be wrong.

Comment: yes yes sorry I am not english native, I mean sin(v)

Comment: Does $u=xy$ and $v=xz$? How are $u$ and $v$ related to $x,y,z$?

Comment: yes sure, u will be xy and v will be xz